# Slow connection between java jpa application and a remote Mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have a strange situation with my java play framework (2.3) application. All works fine If I have deployed my applications close (geographically) my database mysql. The request, with connections to database works fine and fast. But, last day, I moved the database remotely, in another country. The application go on  fine, but, each time I create a JPA Entity Manager (and I think the application create a new connections to remote database)  the connections is very very slowly. And the result is that all request are extremely slow.

According your experience there is a way to optimize this situation via application?

Below my controller java code:

```
@Transactional
public Result testperson() {
    Person person= JPAEntityManager.find(Person .class, "XXXXXX");
    person.setAddress("XXXXXXX");
    JPA.em().persist(person);
    return ok("");
}
```

The @Transactional annotation intercept a play framework jpa implementation for the connections:

```
public static <T> F.Promise<T> withTransactionAsync(String name, boolean readOnly, play.libs.F.Function0<F.Promise<T>> block) throws Throwable {
        EntityManager em = null;
        EntityTransaction tx = null;
        try {

            em = JPA.em(name);
            JPA.bindForCurrentThread(em);

            if(!readOnly) {
                tx = em.getTransaction();
                tx.begin();
            }

            F.Promise<T> result = block.apply();

            final EntityManager fem = em;
            final EntityTransaction ftx = tx;

            F.Promise<T> committedResult = result.map(new F.Function<T, T>() {
                @Override
                public T apply(T t) throws Throwable {
                    try {
                        if(ftx != null) {
                            if(ftx.getRollbackOnly()) {
                                ftx.rollback();
                            } else {
                                ftx.commit();
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        fem.close();
                    }
                    return t;
                }
            });

            committedResult.onFailure(new F.Callback<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void invoke(Throwable t) {
                    if (ftx != null) {
                        try { if (ftx.isActive()) ftx.rollback(); } catch(Throwable e) {}
                    }
                    fem.close();
                }
            });

            return committedResult;

        } catch(Throwable t) {
            if(tx != null) {
                try { tx.rollback(); } catch(Throwable e) {}
            }
            if(em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
            throw t;
        } finally {
            JPA.bindForCurrentThread(null);
        }
    }
```

The JPA.em() create a new EntityManager...

All connections details are default for the play framework: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsJDBC

Maybe Is there a problem with MySQl database during remote connections?
Can there be some settings to set on the database side to improve a remote connection?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually this happens when JPA starts to eagerly load data and suddenly there are 10s on 100s of statements going to the DB. This becomes more noticeable if the DB and app are not collocated. If you run the app locally and configure hibernate to show the SQL statements, do you see a lot of queries being executed? And I assume you are using a connection pool, it would be good to know its configuration.

Comment: The connection pool is the default managed by the applications. I do not see a lot of query executed at startup... This latency occurs for all calls, whenever a new entity manager is created, for this reasong I do not thinks that is a eager/lazy loading data...

Answer (score 0):

How long does `SELECT 1` take?  That gives you a good clue of the *new* overhead for *every* SQL statement because of reaching into "another country".

If it turns out that there are "too many" queries, consider wrapping a set of them in a Stored Procedure.  Then have your app `CALL` the SP -- this will be one roundtrip, not many.

Comment: Thanks to answer. After hours of debugging I figure out better the connection beahviour I understand that is too slowly the creation of database connections, and also obtaing a connections from the connections pool. So Is there  a way to improve this performance?